# How do I select everything after the last instance of?

Tags: c#, linq

I asked yesterday how to select everything after the first instance of a flag in a collection and the answer was to use SkipWhile which work great. But now the logic has changed, and I need a way to Select the last instance of and everything after it.

A bit more detail:
The list contains an ordered list with a number of configurations, and each has a flag called IsTop. What I need to do is find the last instance of IsTop == true, grab that and everything after it.

Can this be done in LINQ or do I have to ToArray() it and do it by hand, so to speak?

Comment: You can use `Take(length)`

Comment: How is the list ordered? If it's sorted by IsTop that would make a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reverse` to handle this, and swap out `SkipWhile` for `TakeWhile`.

```
var query = sequence.Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(item => !item.IsTop)
    .Reverse(); //to get back in the original order; remove if not needed
```

Unfortunately, the above method doesn't include the last item where `IsTop` is true, to do so is a tad more complex, and the "easiest" methods of doing so would involve iterating the sequence several times, as such it should really only be used on a `List`, `Array`, or other data structure that can access items by index (i.e., an `IList`).  Here is a method that would be able to handle it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Foo<T>(IList<T> data, Func<T, bool> isDivisor)
{
    int itemsToTake = data.Reverse()
        .TakeWhile(isDivisor)
        .Count() + 1;

    return data.Skip(data.Count - itemsToTake);
}
```

Another approach that is more "proper", relies on a helper method.  This method will group items while a predicate indicates it should be.  If the predicate returns true it is added to the "current group", if it's false, the previous group is "done" and a new group is started.  This helper method is as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (predicate(iterator.Current))
            {
                list.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
            }
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Using this it's actually rather straightforward:

```
var query = sequence.GroupWhile(item => !item.IsTop)
    .Last();
```

Conceptually this models what we're doing the best.  We're creating groups in which each group goes from one `IsTop` item to the next, and then we just want the last group (or the first group, for your other question).

Comment: This is almost right, but doesn't take the last one with `IsTop == true`, which he wants.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic `Reverse` on a list is void, `Reverse` on an `IEnumerable` does not.  Use `AsEnumerable` if you have a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own simple extension method to do this:

```
// takes items until the first one where predicate is true;
// includes the first item where predicate is true
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeUntil<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        if (predicate(item))
            break;
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeLastUntil<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
{
    return source.Reverse().TakeUntil(predicate).Reverse();
}
```

Use like:

```
var myList = new[]
{
    new { IsTop = false, S = 'a' },
    new { IsTop = true, S = 'b' },
    new { IsTop = false, S = 'c' },
    new { IsTop = true, S = 'd' },
    new { IsTop = false, S = 'e' },
}.ToList();
myList.TakeLastUntil(x => x.IsTop); // has d and e
```

This might iterate the list more than is necessary. If that's a problem (e.g. because you have a very long list) and you are working with some sort of `IList<T>` instead of just an `IEnumerable<T>`, it should be possible to write these methods more efficiently for `IList<T>`.